# Migrating db entities to node js application using ORM from an existing db

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am currently trying to migrate my db entities  from an existing db to node js express application. I tried with sequelize-auto but somewhere I'm getting stuck and could not achieve it. My questions are is it possible to migrate all tables with associations to node js. If so please give me some guidelines to achieve it. The database is very big with so many associations between tables. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Node.js is not a database, it cannot store tables.

Comment: Im trying create ORM in nodejs